# VBA Raising event on another class

Tags: excel, vba, events, rubberduck

I am trying to implement the suggestions from [this post in codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/235295/197645)

**Objective:**

Manage what happens when users interact with Excel Tables (ListObjects)

The idea at the end is to have custom events for different tables. e.g. When you add a row to table1 the custom AddEvent1 is raised, and when you do the same to table2, AddEvent2 is raised.

There would be only one class to manage the events and one to hold the tables and their information.

---

**So the process suggested is to:**

1. Add the listobject to a class called `Table`
2. That class would listen to the events on the parent sheet (`Change` and `SelectionChange`)
3. When a change event is fired, trigger a custom event from a class `TableManager` that handles those events (events like `adding`, `updating` or `deleting` rows)

---

**EDIT #1:**

Adjusted the code:

- The `Create` function now returns an instance of a `Table`
- And the property `Set SourceTable` now sets the `listObjectParentSheet` field to the corresponding value

But still the `Table Manager` doesn't listen to the event raised in  `listObjectParentSheet_Change`

---

**Components:**

1) A Sheet with an Excel Table (ListObject) and the following code behind:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

    Dim myTable As Table
    Dim myTableManager As TableManager

    Set myTable = Table.Create(Me.ListObjects(1))

    Set myTableManager = New TableManager

    Set myTableManager.TableInstance = myTable

End Sub
```

2) Class `Table` (with a predeclared id set to true using [rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com/))

```
'@Folder("VBAProject")

Option Explicit
'@PredeclaredId

Private Type TTable
    SourceTable As ListObject
End Type

Private this As TTable

Private WithEvents listObjectParentSheet As Excel.Worksheet

Public Event AddEvent()

Public Property Get SourceTable() As ListObject
    Set SourceTable = this.SourceTable
End Property

Public Property Set SourceTable(ByVal value As ListObject)
    Set this.SourceTable = value
    Set listObjectParentSheet = value.Parent
End Property

Public Property Get Self() As Table
    Set Self = Me
End Property

Public Function Create(ByVal EvalSourceTable As ListObject) As Table
    With New Table
        Set .SourceTable = EvalSourceTable
        Set Create = .Self
    End With
End Function

Private Sub listObjectParentSheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, SourceTable.DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox listObjectParentSheet.Name & " " & Target.Address
        RaiseEvent AddEvent
    End If
End Sub
```

3) Class `TableManager`

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents m_table As Table

Public Property Get TableInstance() As Table
    Set TableInstance = m_table
End Property

Public Property Set TableInstance(ByRef tableObject As Table)
    Set m_table = tableObject
End Property

Private Sub m_table_AddEvent()
    MsgBox "Adding something"
End Sub
```

---

**Question/issue:**

I haven't figure out how to fire the "AddEvent" in the `TableManager` class. I know I have messed up some concepts of instantiating the classes, but I don't know what I am doing wrong.

---

**Expected result:**

When user changes any cell of the listobject, show the message box "Adding something" when the `AddEvent` is raised

---

Any help would be really appreciated.

**EDIT #2**

Final code thanks to Mat's answer:

Sheet: `Sheet1`:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    With TableManager
        Set .TableEvents = Table.Create(Sheet1.ListObjects(1))
    End With
End Sub
```

Module: `ListObjectUtilities`

```
Option Explicit

Public Function GetCellRow(ByVal EvalTable As ListObject, ByVal EvalCell As Range) As Long

    If Intersect(EvalCell, EvalTable.DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then Exit Function

    GetCellRow = EvalCell.Row - EvalTable.HeaderRowRange.Row

End Function

Public Function GetCellColumn(ByVal EvalTable As ListObject, ByVal EvalCell As Range) As Long

    If Intersect(EvalCell, EvalTable.DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then Exit Function

    GetCellColumn = EvalCell.Column - EvalTable.HeaderRowRange.Column + 1

End Function
```

Class: `ITable`

```
Option Explicit

Public Property Get SourceTable() As ListObject
End Property
```

Class: `Table`

```
'@Folder("VBAProject")
'@PredeclaredId
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents TableSheet As Excel.Worksheet

Private Type TTable
    SourceTable As ListObject
    LastRowCount As Long
    LastColumnCount As Long
End Type

Private this As TTable

Public Event Changed(ByVal cell As Range)
Public Event AddedNewRow(ByVal newRow As ListRow)
Public Event AddedNewColumn(ByVal newColumn As ListColumn)

Implements ITable

Public Function Create(ByVal Source As ListObject) As ITable
    With New Table
        Set .SourceTable = Source
        Set Create = .Self
    End With
End Function

Public Property Get Self() As Table
    Set Self = Me
End Property

Public Property Get SourceTable() As ListObject
    Set SourceTable = this.SourceTable
End Property

Public Property Set SourceTable(ByVal value As ListObject)
    ThrowIfSet this.SourceTable
    ThrowIfNothing value
    Set TableSheet = value.Parent
    Set this.SourceTable = value
    Resize
End Property

Friend Sub OnChanged(ByVal Target As Range)
    RaiseEvent Changed(Target)
End Sub

Friend Sub OnAddedNewRow(ByVal newRow As ListRow)
    RaiseEvent AddedNewRow(newRow)
End Sub

Friend Sub OnAddedNewColumn(ByVal newColumn As ListColumn)
    RaiseEvent AddedNewColumn(newColumn)
End Sub

Private Sub ThrowIfNothing(ByVal Target As Object)
    If Target Is Nothing Then Err.Raise 5, TypeName(Me), "Argument cannot be a null reference."
End Sub

Private Sub ThrowIfSet(ByVal Target As Object)
    If Not Target Is Nothing Then Err.Raise 5, TypeName(Me), "This reference is already set."
End Sub

Private Sub Resize()
    With this.SourceTable
        this.LastRowCount = .ListRows.Count
        this.LastColumnCount = .ListColumns.Count
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub TableSheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Intersect(Target, SourceTable.DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Select Case True
    Case this.SourceTable.DataBodyRange.Columns.Count > this.LastColumnCount
        OnAddedNewColumn SourceTable.ListColumns(ListObjectUtilities.GetCellColumn(this.SourceTable, Target))
    Case this.SourceTable.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count > this.LastRowCount
        OnAddedNewRow SourceTable.ListRows(ListObjectUtilities.GetCellRow(this.SourceTable, Target))
    Case Else
        OnChanged Target
    End Select
    Resize
End Sub

Private Property Get ITable_SourceTable() As ListObject
    Set ITable_SourceTable = this.SourceTable
End Property
```

Class: `TableManager`

```
'@Folder("VBAProject")
'@PredeclaredId
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents MyTable As Table

Public Property Get TableEvents() As Table
    Set TableEvents = MyTable
End Property

Public Property Set TableEvents(ByVal value As Table)
    Set MyTable = value
End Property

Private Sub MyTable_AddedNewColumn(ByVal newColumn As ListColumn)
    MsgBox "Added new column " & newColumn.Range.Column
End Sub

Private Sub MyTable_AddedNewRow(ByVal newRow As ListRow)
    MsgBox "Added new row " & newRow.Range.Row
End Sub

Private Sub MyTable_Changed(ByVal cell As Range)
    MsgBox "Changed " & cell.Address
End Sub
```

[Sample file](https://1drv.ms/x/s!ArAKssDW3T7wnL1MpifPKsQQayr7fQ?e=EuofSs)

Comment: You can only fire an event from the class that defines it. Are you trying to fire `Table.AddEvent` from within `TableManager`? I don't understand why you would want to do that....

Comment: Part of the problem is that the `Create` factory method isn't creating anything... It's mutating the default instance, making it stateful...

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Thanks for your response. Yes I'm trying to fire Table.AddEvent. I tried to create an instance using `With New`, but then I couldn't set the `listObjectParentSheet` variable to the parent sheet.

Comment: That'd be `Set .SourceTable = EvalSourceTable` ...you can't assign to the private field. And that setter is what should be assigning the `WithEvents` field.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I had that way before, but how could I set that the listObjectParentSheet variable listens only to the sheet that is holding the ListObject? Do you agree with the approach suggested [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/235295/197645)? I think it simplificates stuff, but I haven't figure out how to implement it.

Comment: If you assign the private `WithEvents` field from inside the `Public Property Set SourceTable` member, the private field will always be referring to the correct sheet... This type of thing is *exactly* why properties exist

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Thanks. That part of assigning the private field is now clear and I fixed the `Create` factory method. But the `RaiseEvent AddEvent`isn't still listened by the TableManager class. Is it the way I'm setting the instance? `Set myTableManager.TableInstance = myTable`

Comment: Make sure Create is really returning the object that's being newed up and whose properties are being assigned, and that the event handler signature matches the event definition. If you put the caret inside the handler and it says "(general)" in the top-left code pane dropdown, then that handler is dead code; the left -side dropdown should contain the name of the event provider variable (m_Table).

Comment: @MathieuGuindon it is returning the object and the event handler has the name of the event at the right `AddEvent`.

Comment: Are you hitting a breakpoint in the worksheet changed handler?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Yeap. This one is executed listObjectParentSheet_SelectionChange

Comment: At this point I lost track of what your code does... mind editing to update the code with what you've got now? Thanks!

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Done! see Edit#1

Comment: @RicardoDiaz, this is really cool.  Are you keeping this class project alive somewhere? (e.g. GitHub)

Comment: @rsd I used it in a couple of projects. Helped me a lot, but sincerily I didn't have more time to invest in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to repro, but then found that relying on `Worksheet.Activate` to register the handler, tends to misbehave: sometimes you need to "wiggle" the sheet so it keeps up, especially if you're editing the code. Could be just that :)

Note that in order to be able to fire `AddedNewRow`, `AddedNewColumn`, or even `RemovedRow` or `RemovedColumn`, you'll need to constantly track the size of the table with a mix of `Worksheet.Change` and `Worksheet.SelectionChange` handlers.

**Table** class module:

```
'@Folder("VBAProject")
'@PredeclaredId
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents TableSheet As Excel.Worksheet

Private Type TTable
    SourceTable As ListObject
    LastRowCount As Long
    LastColumnCount As Long
End Type

Private this As TTable

Public Event Changed(ByVal cell As Range)
Public Event AddedNewRow(ByVal newRow As ListRow)
Public Event AddedNewColumn(ByVal newColumn As ListColumn)

Public Function Create(ByVal Source As ListObject) As Table
    With New Table
        Set .SourceTable = Source
        Set Create = .Self
    End With
End Function

Public Property Get Self() As Table
    Set Self = Me
End Property

Public Property Get SourceTable() As ListObject
    Set SourceTable = this.SourceTable
End Property

Public Property Set SourceTable(ByVal Value As ListObject)
    ThrowIfSet this.SourceTable
    ThrowIfNothing Value
    Set TableSheet = Value.Parent
    Set this.SourceTable = Value
    Resize
End Property

Friend Sub OnChanged(ByVal Target As Range)
    RaiseEvent Changed(Target)
End Sub

Friend Sub OnAddedNewRow(ByVal newRow As ListRow)
    RaiseEvent AddedNewRow(newRow)
End Sub

Friend Sub OnAddedNewColumn(ByVal newColumn As ListColumn)
    RaiseEvent AddedNewColumn(newColumn)
End Sub

Private Sub ThrowIfNothing(ByVal Target As Object)
    If Target Is Nothing Then Err.Raise 5, TypeName(Me), "Argument cannot be a null reference."
End Sub

Private Sub ThrowIfSet(ByVal Target As Object)
    If Not Target Is Nothing Then Err.Raise 5, TypeName(Me), "This reference is already set."
End Sub

Private Sub Resize()
    With this.SourceTable
        this.LastRowCount = .ListRows.Count
        this.LastColumnCount = .ListColumns.Count
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub TableSheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not (Target.ListObject Is SourceTable) Then Exit Sub
    OnChanged Target
    Resize
End Sub
```

Note that you can use the `Is` operator to determine whether `Target.ListObject` refers to the same object as `SourceTable`, instead of using `Application.Intersect` with ranges:

```
If Not (Target.ListObject Is SourceTable) Then Exit Sub
```

From there all we need is a class to handle this `Changed` event - I've put that in the `Sheet1` code-behind here, but any class module will do (including a `UserForm` module):

**Sheet1** worksheet module:

```
'@Folder("VBAProject")
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents MyTable As Table

Public Property Get TableEvents() As Table
    Set TableEvents = MyTable
End Property

Public Property Set TableEvents(ByVal value As Table)
    Set MyTable = value
End Property

Private Sub MyTable_Changed(ByVal cell As Range)
    MsgBox "Changed " & cell.Address
End Sub
```

The `Table` reference still needs to be `Set` somewhere - here in the `Open` handler of the host workbook:

**ThisWorkbook** workbook module:

```
'@Folder("VBAProject")
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    With Sheet1
        Set .TableEvents = Table.Create(.ListObjects(1))
    End With
End Sub
```

---

The next step would be to clean up the public interface returned by `Table.Create` - as it stands, things are pretty confusing and the `Table` interface is a bit bloated:

[image: Public and Friend members of the Table interface]

All these members will be available to `Sheet1.TableEvents`, unless we do something. What if we could only expose the members the client code *really* needs, like this?

[image: Only the SourceTable member is listed for the object returned by Table.Create]

With [Rubberduck](http://www.github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck) you can *extract an interface* by right-clicking anywhere in the `Table` class and selecting "Extract Interface" from the "Refactor" menu, and then pick the members to extract - here the `SourceTable` getter (we're not going to expose the setter!):

[image: Rubberduck's Extract Method refactoring]

This creates a new private class (this will change in future releases) - make it `PublicNotCreatable` in the *properties* toolwindow (F4) if the interface was extracted out of a public class.

The refactoring will add `Implements ITable` at the top of the `Table` class (assuming you didn't rename the interface), and this member will be added:

```
Private Property Get ITable_SourceTable() As ListObject
    Err.Raise 5 'TODO implement interface member
End Property
```

All you need to do is to supply the implementation:

```
Private Property Get ITable_SourceTable() As ListObject
    Set ITable_SourceTable = this.SourceTable
End Property
```

And now `Table.Create` can return the `ITable` abstraction:

```
Public Function Create(ByVal Source As ListObject) As ITable
```

Comment: This is awesome. You really know how to solve things. Thank you @Mathieu! I'll post the final code in my question.